# How to Synchronize .sdf Database to .mdf Database & .mdf Database to .sdf Database?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, mdf, sdf

I have a project running on the tablet device which has .sdf file as database.

Now the database is set into the server for normal devices(Pcs).

How can i synchronise the data between .sdf file and .mdf file(server to .sdf file)

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am assuming you want to synchronize the contents of your SQL Compact SDF file to SQL Server rather than synchronizing the files themselves.

Have a look at: Tutorial: [Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

or [Walkthrough: Creating an Occasionally Connected Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384472.aspx)